# Pandas: Find values within multiple ranges defined by start- and stop-columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use two columns `start` and `stop` to define multiple ranges of values in another dataframe's `age` column. Ranges are defined in a df called `intervals`:

```
start  stop
    1     3
    5     7
```

Ages are defined in another df:

```
age  some_random_value
  1                100
  2                200
  3                300
  4                400
  5                500
  6                600
  7                700
  8                800
  9                900
 10               1000
```

Desired output is values where `age` is between the ranges defined in `intervals` (1-3 and 5-7):

```
age  some_random_value
  1                100
  2                200
  3                300
  5                500
  6                600
  7                700
```

I've tried using numpy.r_ but it doesn't work quite as I want it to:

```
df.age.loc[pd.np.r_[intervals.start, intervals.stop]]
```

Which yields:

```
age  some_random_value
  2                200
  6                600
  4                400
  8                800
```

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe need parameter `closed='both'` in [`IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['start'], df2['stop'], 'both')
```

And then select matching values:

```
df = df[intervals.get_indexer(df.age.values) != -1]
print (df)
   age  some_random_value
0    1                100
1    2                200
2    3                300
4    5                500
5    6                600
6    7                700
```

**Detail**:

```
print (intervals.get_indexer(df.age.values))
[ 0  0  0 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Do you mind explaining the `!= -1` part in `intervals.get_indexer(df.age.values) != -1`?

Comment: @Plasma - Sure, if not match get `-1`, so filter values if not `-1`

Comment: Alright, but what determines if the value is 0 or 1?

Comment: It create for each interval range of values - here are 2 rows in sample, so for `1-3` create `0`, for `5-7` create `1` and if multiple rows it continue this way

Comment: So if add interval `8-9` get `2` values

Comment: Oh ok, and mismatches are always -1. Thanks a lot!